# How to centeralize a label after hiding an image next to it

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, constraints, uilabel

I have a custom cell that has an image and a label in it next to each other. I am reusing the custom cell in another place but I have a condition that hides the image.

How do I set the label to be centered after hiding the image?

I tried to set the text alignment to center but it didn't work.

```
 if (condition) == false{
            self.checkImage.isHidden = true
        }
        else {
            self.checkImage.isHidden = false
        }
```

Comment: Try using StackView.

Comment: Above line can be `self.checkImage.isHidden = !condition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy option is to put both the `imageView` and the `label` inside a horizontal `stackView` which will make the label centered when you set `isHidden` to the `imageView`

**Or**

Make an outlet of the `imageView` width and set it's constant to zero

Comment: This helped me also, you should remove leading constraint between icon and text